# Best version of google chrome for Selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Can anyboby please suggest the best version of google chrome for Selenium Webdriver java.Im using webdriver 44 on windows 7. My code runs correctly in firefox but fails to run in google chrome.

Comment: What error do you getting when run with chrome?

Comment: I didn't got any error, just the code got struct at point which is the issue due to version of google chrome.just need to know the standard version of chrome

Comment: For me it is working perfect in chrome version 43.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the latest chrome drive here:

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

This should work with WebDriver as it is working for me.